# Components are not loading with VueRouter

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I have been trying to setup a simple vue application using VueRouter with Laravel. But the vue-router is not loading the components properly.

welcome.blade.php

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
     <main-app/>
  </div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
//import Vue from 'vue';
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import {
    routes
} from './routes';
import MainApp from './components/MainApp.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: {
        MainApp
    }
});
```

routes.js

```
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
export const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: Home,
    name: 'Home'
}];
```

MainApp.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

If `http://localhost:8080/vue-spa` is dialed, "Home component" should be displayed (which we are displaying in Home.vue). But , nothing is displaying.

[Screenshot of Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXDci.png)

I am new to Vue , help to find a solution for this.

Comment: instead of doing `window.Vue = require('vue')`, please do `window.Vue = Vue`; Let me know if that changes anything

Comment: @MatthiasS No , the output is same.

Comment: Maybe you should put the `window.Vue = require('vue')` on top and remove the `import Vue from ' vue'` part. I am not sure if it changes things but I don't like importing vue twice in the same file through different methods.
Can you go to `MainApp.vue` and add this to the `created`hook: `console.log(this.$router, this.$route)`

Comment: Its not printing to console. Its not loading Home component. But I am not getting why its not loading

Comment: But if its not printing anything, it means it is not even loading MainApp.vue. So it is maybe not even a router problem.

Comment: In developer tools , I can see the MainApp component. But Home component is not loaded.

Comment: Well since the `path` of the route is set to `/`, why do you expect you will see anything at `/vue-spa`? Those need to match :)

Comment: I even tried by setting the route to `/home` and dialiing `localhost:8080/vue-spa/home` from url . But its throwing 404.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes.js should be -

```
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
export const routes = [{
    path: '/vue-spa',
    component: Home,
    name: 'Home'
}];
```

Also, make sure the following is done -

- You have executed the `npm install` command in your project. This will install the `laravel-mix` package, necessary for compiling your js files. ([Learn more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix))
- Then once you have your laravel-mix installed, configure the webpack.mix.js file present in your root folder. In your case (assuming the app.js file where you have written your js code is present in resources/js) the webpack.mix.js should look like -

  ```
  const mix = require('laravel-mix');

  mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
  ```

This will yield the compiled resourses/js/app.js file in public/js/app.js

- Once that is done execute `npm run watch`. This will recompile the public/js/app.js file every time you make any changes in your resources/js/app.js code or its imported files.
- Another very important step would be to set up Laravel's routes so that any request the server receives gives an entry point to your vue.js SPA. This is the probable reason that you are getting a 404 page. Define the following route in your web.php to enable that -

  ```
  <?php

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Web Routes
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
  | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
  | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
  |
  */

  Route::view('/{any}', 'welcome')->where('any', '.*');
  ```

Comment: Hey Vedant, thank you for your reply . I have followed all the steps mentioned above, before posting this question and one more thing regarding `routes.js` file is:  `vue-spa` is the application , so , I thought setting path to `/` would be appropriate. Please, correct me , if I am wrong.

Comment: If that is the case you should simply try running `localhost:8000` or `localhost:8080`. There is a need to explicitly define the app name in the route. It's just the url's path that you are opening should match some path in your vue's routes. For example if you are opening `localhost:8000/foo/bar` your vue router must have the path `/foo/bar` defined. Also please check that I have updated the Laravel's route in my answer. Apologies I posted the wrong route earlier.

Comment: Hey , Thank you for your detailed answer . Home component is displaying after making the chanes in routes and web.php